# How can I get participant/organization inside convector controllers?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, convector

I want to get participant model inside controller, but I only have identity/fingerprint....
The question is how to get the participant model?

Answer (score 1):

the answer is use the identity/fingerprint with a rich couchdb query.

> inside controller use `this.sender` to get fingerprint ex `B5:38:A3:84:02:D1:EE:2B:CD:25:27:66:C0:F6:9E:4F:91:16:21:EE`

next, first create the worldstate query, and test it in fauxton

query

```
{
   "selector": {
      "type": "io.worldsibu.examples.participant",
      "identities": {
         "$elemMatch": {
            "fingerprint": "B5:38:A3:84:02:D1:EE:2B:CD:25:27:66:C0:F6:9E:4F:91:16:21:EE",
            "status": true
         }
      }
   }
}
```

done with query

now create a utils.ts to be shared in controllers like

`packages/person-cc/src/utils.ts`

```
import { appConstants as c } from '@convector-rest-sample/common';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { Participant } from 'participant-cc';

const bcryptSaltRounds: number = 10;

export const hashPassword = (password: string): string => {
  return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcryptSaltRounds);
};

/**
 * get Participant by Identity/Fingerprint
 */
export const getParticipantByIdentity = async (fingerprint: string): Promise<Participant> => {
  const participant: Participant | Participant[] = await Participant.query(Participant, {
    selector: {
      type: c.CONVECTOR_MODEL_PATH_PARTICIPANT,
      identities: {
        $elemMatch: {
          fingerprint,
          status: true
        }
      }
    }
  });

  if (!!participant && !participant[0].id) {
    throw new Error('Cant find a participant with that fingerprint');
  }
  return participant[0];
}
```

now use it in one controller

```
...
import { getParticipantByIdentity, hashPassword } from './utils';

@Controller('person')
export class PersonController extends ConvectorController<ChaincodeTx> {
  @Invokable()
  public async create(
    @Param(Person)
    person: Person
  ) {
    // get host participant from fingerprint
    const participant: Participant = await getParticipantByIdentity(this.sender);
    if (!!participant && !participant.id) {
      throw new Error('There is no participant with that identity');
    }
...
```

done, now deploy chaincode and test with

```
npx hurl invoke $CC person_create "{\"id\":\"1-100-100\",\"firstname\":\"Pete\",\"lastname\":\"Doe\",\"username\":\"peter\",\"password\":\"12345678\",\"email\":\"pete.doe@example.com\"}" -u admin
```

check couchdb

```
{
  "_id": "1-100-100",
  "_rev": "1-2b08d163d01dcfa5b9e9dc31bcc3b50c",
  "email": "pete.doe@example.com",
  "firstname": "Pete",
  "id": "1-100-103",
  "lastname": "Doe",
  "participant": {
    "id": "gov",
    "identities": [
      {
        "fingerprint": "B5:38:A3:84:02:D1:EE:2B:CD:25:27:66:C0:F6:9E:4F:91:16:21:EE",
        "status": true
      }
    ],
    "msp": "org1MSP",
    "name": "Big Government",
    "type": "io.worldsibu.examples.participant"
  },
  "password": "$2b$10$IYsgUSb/RA6zr4tT3u10HugCrxJH2loLsVUKjTkTiAAj3yewnR2SO",
  "roles": [
    "USER"
  ],
  "type": "io.worldsibu.examples.person",
  "username": "peter",
  "~version": "\u0000CgMBDgA="
}
```

done